# Parametric CDF estimation for exponential distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution, maximum-likelihood

Suppose we have a random sample $(X_{1}, \dots,X_{n})$, where $X_{i}$ follows an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Hence, we have the following:

$$F(x) = 1 - \exp(-\lambda x)$$

$$\mathbb{E}(X_{i}) = \dfrac{1}{\lambda}$$

$$\text{Var}(X_{i}) = \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{2}}$$

I know that the MLE estimator is $\hat{\lambda} = \dfrac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}}$.

I am interested in estimating the CDF at the point $x = 1$, hence what I have is

$$\hat{F(1)} = 1 - \exp(- \hat{\lambda})$$

I want to discover if it is biased or not:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left( \hat{F}(1) \right) &= 1 - \mathbb{E}(\exp(- \hat{\lambda}))
\end{align*}

Any clues how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to discover if it is biased or not:

The question is only to detect if the estimator is biased or not. They do not ask you to explicitly calculate the expectation of your estimator. Thus the solution is very easy: using Jensen's inequality you get

$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{F(1)}]=\mathbb{E}\Bigg[1-e^{-\frac{1}{\overline{X}_n}}\Bigg]\ne 1-e^{-\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[\overline{X}_n]}}=1-e^{-\lambda}$$

Thus your estimator is biased

EDIT: I supposed it was easy also to calculate the needed expectation explicitly passing by Gamma function but I was wrong...the integral can be solved numerically... thus the solution (IMHO) is the one I showed

Comment: why is the function $f(x) = 1-e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ convex or concave? If I am not mistaken its second derivative is $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}(\frac{2}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^4})$, which is neither always positive nor always negative.

Comment: I know how to do it with Gamma functions, I was just pointing out that I think that what you said is wrong. For example, what about a non- constant random variable and $f(x) = (x+a)^3$ for a suitable $a$? Just take $a = \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^3-\mathbb{E}[X^3]}{3(Var(X))}$ (hope I did the calculations right)